# Using an extended MediaItem in audio_service v18

Tags: flutter, audio-service

I'm looking to extend MediaItem so that I can easily add extra metadata with custom classes, which I can't do with the extras property (using extras is also more awkward than if my extra info was just part of the class). I've tried extending MediaItem, but when I change the function arguments in my BaseAudioHandler, it says that it is an invalid override. Here is an example of my class. Most of it is copy-pasted from MediaItem:

```dart
class CustomMediaItem extends MediaItem {
  final CustomClass customValue;

  CustomMediaItem({
    /// A unique id.
    required final String id,

    /// The title of this media item.
    required final String title,

    /// The album this media item belongs to.
    final String? album,

    /// The artist of this media item.
    final String? artist,

    /// The genre of this media item.
    final String? genre,

    /// The duration of this media item.
    final Duration? duration,

    /// The artwork for this media item as a uri.
    final Uri? artUri,

    /// Whether this is playable (i.e. not a folder).
    final bool? playable = true,

    /// Override the default title for display purposes.
    final String? displayTitle,

    /// Override the default subtitle for display purposes.
    final String? displaySubtitle,

    /// Override the default description for display purposes.
    final String? displayDescription,

    /// The rating of the media item.
    final Rating? rating,

    /// A map of additional metadata for the media item.
    ///
    /// The values must be of type `int`, `String`, `bool` or `double`.
    final Map<String, dynamic>? extras,
    required this.customClass,
  }) : super(
          id: id,
          title: title,
          album: album,
          artist: artist,
          genre: genre,
          duration: duration,
          artUri: artUri,
          playable: playable,
          displayTitle: displayTitle,
          displaySubtitle: displaySubtitle,
          displayDescription: displayDescription,
          rating: rating,
          extras: extras,
        );
}
```

When I try to replace an argument in my BaseAudioHandler, I get this:

```
'MusicPlayerBackgroundTask.addQueueItem' ('Future<void> Function(CustomMediaItem)') isn't a valid override of 'BaseAudioHandler.addQueueItem' ('Future<void> Function(MediaItem)').dart(invalid_override)
```

I also tried creating my own AudioHandler, but it gave the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `extras` property designed for that purpose. From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/0.18.0-beta.0/audio_service/MediaItem/extras.html) of `MediaItem`:

> #### extras property
>
> `Map<String, dynamic>? extras`
> *final*
>
> A map of additional metadata for the media item.
>
> The values must be of type `int`, `String`, `bool` or `double`.

So if you wanted to store an extra boolean metadata called `isPreview`, you would do something like:

```dart
final item = MediaItem(
  id: 'id1',
  title: 'Song title',
  album: 'Album title',
  extras: {
    'isPreview': true,
  },
);
```

There is no limit to how many extra properties you can store in the `extras` map.